# Lambda functions as class members

Tags: c++, c++11, functor, lambda

Is it possible to accept two different types of lambda function as class members **without knowing their template arguments ahead of time?**

```
struct two_functors {
    std::function<???> a;
    std::function<???> b;
    ...
};
```

Such that something like this would be possible:

```
void main(){
    vector<two_functors> many_functors;

    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    double c = 4.7;
    double d = 8.4;

    two_functors add_and_subtract;
    add_and_subtract.a = [a, b](int x, int y){cout << x + y << endl;};
    add_and_subtract.b = [c, d](double x, double y){cout << x - y << endl;};

    two_functors multiply_and_divide;
    multiply_and_divide.a = [c, d](double x, double y){cout << x * y << endl;};
    multiply_and_divide.b = [a, b](int x, int y){cout << x / y << endl;};

    many_functors.push_back(add_and_subtract);
    many_functors.push_back(multiply_and_divide);

    for (auto functors : many_functors){
        functors.a();
        functors.b();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could be done using templates, I expect...

Comment: Can `two_functors` be a class template?  Aren't `add_and_print.a()` and `add_and_print.b()` incorrect without some arguments to pass as `x`, `y`, and `s`?

Comment: The only reason to need to declare something ahead is if something else uses it.  So you expect some statement to use `add_and_print` without having any kind of clue what it contains?  Do you have an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Nesting is probably irrelevant.  You can have a class template nested inside a non-template class.

Comment: @aschepler When there are multiple different two_functors stored in a vector.

Comment: There is no possible way to make a container of functors with differing argument types useful without a whole lot of wrapping and argument-checking code.

Comment: @aschepler Even if you at least know that all the functors return void? I am constructing them at various times, but executing them in sequence all at once, later.

Comment: The latest example still has a conceptual problem: no arguments are passed to `functors.a()` or `functors.b()`.

Comment: I think you're right; could you post an answer explaining why this is impossible?

Comment: @EricB It's possible to have a container of lambdas with different argument types, the catch is that the caller needs to know the signature of the function, which might make sense in the context of a callbacks system. It looks very ugly though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to construct `two_functors` at various times, but execute them later in sequence all at once, you could just use the captured data.

```
struct two_functors
{
    function<void ()> a;
    function<void ()> b;
};

int main()
{
    vector<two_functors> many_functors;

    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    double c = 4.7;
    double d = 8.4;

    two_functors add_and_subtract {
        [a, b](){cout << a + b << endl;},
        [c, d](){cout << c - d << endl;}
    };

    two_functors multiply_and_divide {
        [c, d](){cout << c * d << endl;},
        [a, b](){cout << a / b << endl;}
    };

    many_functors.push_back(add_and_subtract);
    many_functors.push_back(multiply_and_divide);

    for (auto functors : many_functors){
        functors.a();
        functors.b();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually just what I needed! Thanks, it seems my initial understanding of lambdas was flawed.

Answer (score 2):

That's essentially a [tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple). You can see how the interface is implemented for that.

```
template< class F0, class F1 >
struct two_functors {
   F0 func0;
   F1 func1;
};

template< class F0, class F1 >
two_functors<F0, F1> make_two_functor( F0&& f0, F1&& f1 )
{ 
   // Added [std::forward][2]
   return two_functors<F0,F1>( std::forward<F0>(f0), std::forward<F1>(f1) ); 
}
```

Comment: `auto f1 = []{}; auto result = make_two_functor( f1, f1 );` uses struct members with reference type.  I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: `std::make_tuple` uses `std::decay<Ti>::type` as the parameters for the returned tuple.  (Ignoring extra logic for `std::ref` and `std::cref`.)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Steven's answer would be to use an intermediate "umbrella" class.

EDIT: Just compiled an example on g++ (GCC) 4.5.3

```
 #include <functional>
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 class myfunction
 {

 };

 template <typename T>
 class specificFunction : public myfunction
 {
     public:
     function<T> f;

     specificFunction(function<T> pf)
     {
         f = pf;
     }
 };

 struct two_functors {
     myfunction* a;
     myfunction* b;
 };



int main()
{
     myfunction* f = new specificFunction<void(int,int)> ([](int a, int b) { cout << a << " - " << b << endl; });
     myfunction* f2 = new specificFunction<void(double,int)> ([](double a, int b) { cout << a << " - " << b << endl; });

     two_functors tf;
     tf.a = f;
     tf.b = f2;

     ((specificFunction<void(int,int)>*)(tf.a))->f(4,5);
     ((specificFunction<void(double,int)>*)(tf.b))->f(4.02,5);

 }
```

Comment: Of course, there's no practical way to do anything useful with a `myfunction*`.

Comment: @aschepler What do you mean? if instead of a struct you put your functions in a container, this is one way to solve it. Can you explain further your comment?

Comment: Sure, you can do `add_and_print.a = make_specificFunction( [a,b](int x, int y) { return x+y; } );`.  But then you can't do `(*add_and_print.a)(4,5);`, because `myfunction` has no `operator()`.

Comment: @aschepler Sure you can, you only need to cast it with the proper signature... Something like ((SpecificConnector<void(int,int)>*)(*add_and_print.a)).f(4,5);

Comment: That stuff between `<` and `>` is not valid as a template argument.

Comment: @aschepler Just fixed it, I had done it that way before, it's ugly but it works.

Comment: At that point you might as well use a `void*`.  Possible to be correct, but a terrible idea.

Comment: @aschepler No, you don't need void* for this. I actually passed for all this trouble to avoid void* usage. I will post a working example in here in a moment.

Comment: Didn't say "need".  And to my first comment, I wouldn't call this "practical".

Comment: @aschepler How else would you solve having a container of lambdas with different signatures?

Answer (score 0):

Not an attempt to answer (I just need the formatting feat), just a variation of Steven's proposal

```
template<typename A, typename B> 
two_functors<A,B> make_two_functors(A&& a, B&& b) {
   return two_functors<A,B> {a, b};
}
```

Does that have any downside compared to using `std::forward<T>`?

*Btw - I somehow wish the need for such "makers" would have vanished with C++11.*

Comment: without std::forward, it can't accept r-value references properly, and the default move constructor for the struct won't be invoked.